# How to implement Multi Dex in Instant Apps?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, android-instant-apps, android-multidex

I am making an instant app. I have the `base feature` and the `installed module`. The two gradle files can't have a `defaultConfig{}`, so that is why I have set `multiDex true` only in the installed `build.gradle` file. Running the **instant app** though throws a compile error as there is no `multiDex` anywhere.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution lies within making two flavours in `base.gradle`:

```
flavorDimensions 'delivery'
productFlavors {
    instant {
        dimension 'delivery'
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkInstant
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    installed {
        dimension 'delivery'
    }
}
```

Note: you still have to add `multiDexEnabled true` in `installed.gradle`'s `defaultConfig{}`
Also put `missingDimensionStrategy 'delivery', 'installed'` in `installed.gradle`'s`defaultConfig{}` and `missingDimensionStrategy 'delivery', 'instant'` in `instant.gradle`'s `defaultConfig{}`